# Kotlin - var property vs object copy

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming

My team has an argument today about var property and object copy. We have an adapter for a RecyclerView. The adapter takes a list of ItemModel, which has a few properties. When any item is clicked, we need to change a property's value of the clicked item.

Some people say we should make the property a var. So, we can assign the new value to it.

Some others say we should make the property val, and use ItemModel.copy and pass the new value to the copy. But to do this, we need to call List.map to create a new list as List is not mutable. This means, to change one property value of one item, we need to loop through the whole list, create a new list with all the items and the new copy of the item that is changed.

In my experiences, the former method looks right to me and the later one does too much unnecessary things and makes bad impact upon performance and resources. But, they were arguing about property mutability and etc. and claimed the later one is a more modern way of programming.

Can anyone with good understanding of android and the functional programming explain for me if the later one really is considered a better way?

Comment: I would recommend using first approach if you've got fewer properties to mutate like one or two. But if you've got scenario where entire model needs to be update except one-two properties later approach is recommended. And yes, later approach is resource consuming as well as having more time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

It being your recyclerview´s list it should be a mutablelist if the recyclerview should mutate the lists item count effectively (create or delete). `val` and `var` on the list does not really matter (in witch case you use `val`) as you don´t need to reassign the list when you create, update or delete the items. Every single of those operations will not reassign the list object. It´s still the same list, just with different items in it. `val` and `var` matters when you want to change value x of item number 3 in the list. Then it (the variable x) has to be `var` for you to be able to change it, but the list does not.

You use `val` to indicated that the value will never be changed. It´s for maintainability so weird bugs don´t happen. Like you have another object referencing that list we talked about before. If the list was a `var` it would be possible to create a new list on the variable and now your two objects no longer point to the same list. Instead one of them still points to the old list. You may not expect that and your program will break. Hence wherever feasible you should be using `val`. Wherever necessary you should be using `var` and not complicate your life trying to preserve `val` unless you have a good reason like this value cannot be changed as it´s referenced all over the place. That's when you use object copy. But not as a default best practice for everything.

That´s just my opinion about it.

On a side note marking a class as a `data class` will generate the copy method for you. So you can copy that object without even requiring to implement copy. Witch is pretty great!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the property as `var` is very tempting, however it can lead to errors that could not be even that easy to reproduce. When you are passing around the reference to an object and there are a couple of places where its content is used and could be changed, you might lost control of the actual application state. The code might become unpredictable.

Immutability is the core of the functional programming. It's purpose is to eliminate such vulnerabilities and help programmers write pieces of code that every time execute as expected, because it eliminates the risk of side effects occurrences.

However, as you and your team noticed, the functional approach sometimes may require additional work and resources. But is it worth it? Well, I don't know how large that list should have been to significantly influence the performance by mapping it. And even if currently your objects aren't shared anywhere, you can't be sure that in the future somebody won't change that. So having in mind that the functional approach is less error-prone, I'd say it is worth it.

Answer (score -1):

The second method is contrary to the Basic Design of Kotlin.

With Kotlin you don't Need to write as much lines of Code as in Java, for example the get and set functions which are included in a class. Why do you want to make your Code longer and more complicated in a Language that was designed to shorten the lines of Code?

Another Point is, longer codes can get hard to read and maintain.

The last Point is, that a copy of a class Needs more ressources and time to create and Access than a Var, for me there is no reason why this should be considered as good Approach.

Comment: That's just an absurd argument. Would you also recommend somebody not to use design patterns because "longer codes can get hard to read and maintain" and "don't make your code longer and more complicated in a language that was designed to shorten the lines of code"?

Comment: I never said i would recommend to not use design Patterns, but in this case it is a much more maintainable and easy to read Code when you set it to var. There may be cases when it is better to stick with val, but not in this case in my oppinion. There is a reason why var exists.

Comment: I'm just saying that your arguments are not proper. Just putting aside the question, sometimes you actually have to write some additional code in order to make the application _more_ maintainable. Also the fact that Kotlin eliminates a lots of boilerplate from Java, doesn't mean that we should write shorter code in Kotlin, because that is _always_ better.

Comment: i am refering to THIS case, not in General. There are cases where you Need to write more Code to Keep it maintainable and you shouldn't Always write Shorter Code in Kotlin because you can.

Comment: Its not contrary to basic design at all though. Since kotlins 'basic design' has a data class that generates copy for you. I agree that it does not necessarily sound like copy would be needed in this case for some viewmodel. But do you know that for certain?